# Como interajo valores específicos de um dataframe com uma função?

Tags: r, funções, dataframe

```
       Idade  AT.49M    AT.83M      AT.2000M
         0    0.00404    0.00269    0.00231
         1    0.00158    0.00105    0.00091
         2    0.00089    0.00059    0.00050
         3    0.00072    0.00048    0.00041
         4    0.00063    0.00042    0.00036
```

Tendo esse dataframe como executo a função

```r
px<-function(a) {
  px=1-a
 return(px)
 }
```

Como faço para interagir um valor específico do df com a função?

EX: quero a função da `idade 2` da `AT.83M`

Answer (score 1):

Use indexação para localizar valores que correspondem à certos critérios:

```
df[df$Idade == 2, "AT.83M"]
# ou
with(df, AT.83M[Idade == 2])
```

Armazene o valor em um objeto ou aplique a função diretamente:

```
> px(df[df$Idade == 2, "AT.83M"])
[1] 0.99941
```

Se está usando R, aprenda indexação. [Esta aula da UFPR](http://cursos.leg.ufpr.br/ecr/indexacao-e-selecao-condicional.html) é uma boa introdução.

Os dados usados:

```
df <- read.table(text = c("
  Idade     AT.49M     AT.83M   AT.2000M
      0    0.00404    0.00269    0.00231
      1    0.00158    0.00105    0.00091
      2    0.00089    0.00059    0.00050
      3    0.00072    0.00048    0.00041
      4    0.00063    0.00042    0.00036"),
  header = TRUE)

px <- function(a) 1-a
```